# rails-admin has_many association to display in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a model user which has_many documents.
On the show page for the user model, I'd like to show the name for each of my documents.

at the moment I'm able to list all documents object, but not accessing the details for each of those documents.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view template, you can have something like this:

```
<% user.documents.each do |document| %>
  ID: <%= document.id %>
  Name: <%= document.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: perfect. so easy !